# Blazor SSR+WASM Persistence poblem

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Im having a hard time making PersistentComponentState work. im not sure if im following all the steps.

1. `@inject PersistentComponentState ApplicationState` on `@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly Component`
2. `OnInitializeAsync Register on Persisting` ApplicationState.RegisterOnPersisting`
3. `OnInitializeAsync` load from `ApplicationState.TryTakeFromJson` or grab from database.
4. `ApplicationState.PersistAsJson` in your Persist handler.

data changes and its updated when prerendering happens, but after webassembly loads everything is lost. and the ApplicationState is empty.  this is an example project with this issue: https://github.com/cosmez/BlazorPersistTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your objects look a little strange [probably unfamiliarity with the context]. `ClientRenderingMode` only has getters: what do you do with it?

Based on what I can see, I think you want to persist initial state of objects, in this case the counter.

I've created a new data object as it's unclear [to me] what `IRenderMode` does.

```cs
public class CounterData
{
    public bool IsClient { get; set; } = true;
    public int Counter { get; set; }

    public CounterData()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        this.Counter = r.Next(10);
    }

    public void Load(CounterData data)
    {
        this.Counter = data.Counter;
        this.IsClient = data.IsClient;
    }
}
```

Registered in both projects:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<CounterData>();
```

I've also added a `RenderContextState` component so you can track state.

```cs
<div class="@_alertCss m-2">
    @_alertText
</div>

@code {
    private bool _rendered;
    private string _alertCss => _rendered ? "alert alert-success" : "alert alert-danger";
    private string _alertText => _rendered ? "Interactively Rendered" : "Statically Rendered";

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _rendered = true;
            // We shouldn't really do this but we need to display the result of the component mutation
            // OnAfterRender should only normally be used for JSInterop code
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And then Counter.  There's no need for internal data values, just use the injected object.  Watch the render state.  Initially loading statically and then after a few seconds interactively.  You'll see the initial server side counter state preserved.

```cs
@page "/counter"
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly
@implements IDisposable
@inject PersistentComponentState ApplicationState
@inject CounterData CounterData

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<RenderContextState />

<h1>Client: @this.CounterData.IsClient</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @this.CounterData.Counter</p>

@code {
    private IDisposable? _persistingSubscription;
    private const string KeyName = "Counter";

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Try to get the persisted state
        var havePersistedState = ApplicationState.TryTakeFromJson<CounterData>(KeyName, out CounterData? counterData);

        // if counterData is not null we need to load the data into the DI object 
        if (counterData is not null)
            this.CounterData.Load(counterData);

        // If we don't have a persisted state then we need to register a handler to persist the state
        // we capture the returned object as IDisposable as all we need to do with it dispose it at the relevant time
        if (!havePersistedState)
            _persistingSubscription = ApplicationState.RegisterOnPersisting(PersistData);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private Task PersistData()
    {
        ApplicationState.PersistAsJson(KeyName, this.CounterData);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
     
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _persistingSubscription?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: i think i understand what the problem is. `havePersistedState` happens only once when wasm loads, and on a full window refresh, but if i navigate to the page using the left menu `PersistData` enters, but `ApplicationState.TryTakeFromJson` returns nothing on WASM.

Comment: I believe `PersistentComponentState` is exclusively for presisting the state from pre-render to render.  If you navigate to the counter page within the SPA i.e. it started on loading `Home`, then there's no pre-render state for counter:  `PersistData` is never caled and `havePersistedState` is false.  Do you want to persist state within the SPA and across SPA loads?